# HTML White Line between td with images (Chrome, Opera, Gmail)

Tags: html, email, line

I have problem with white line margins when writing an email in Chrome, Opera and Gmail with the code below.

If you turn on the developer console you can see that the td surrounding the image is the same size as image, so I'm not sure why there is the extra white space.

[White lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHNc2.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .images {
   width: 100% !important;
  }
  .desktop {
   display: inline;
   mso-table-lspace: 0px;
   mso-table-rspace: 0px;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 660px) {
   td div {
    width: 282px;
    margin: auto;
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
   }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 399px) {
   td div {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 282px;
    margin: auto;
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
   }
  }
 </style>
</head>
  <body>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center">
   <tr>
    <td align="center" width="100%">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
      <tr>
       <td align="center" width="600" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">

                <!-- Start -->
         <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="center" width="600" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #898e92; line-height: normal;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
         </tr>

                <tr>
          <td colspan="3" width="600" align="center">
           <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><img border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/pM0Vjtt.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="images" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."></a>
                  </td>
         </tr>
                <tr>

                 <td width="30" align="center">
                      <img border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/2jAlVvY.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="images" alt="">
                    </td>
                  <td width="215" align="center">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><img border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/2FpjTZk.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="images" alt="Lore"></a>
                  </td>

                  <td width="355" align="center">
                    <img border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/Gob71Qy.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="images" alt="">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" width="600" align="center">
                  <img border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/FKOuWjg.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%;" class="images" alt="">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="center" width="600" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #898e92; line-height: normal;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.          </td>
         </tr>

              </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for information about any errors. Don't know its bug or something weird.